# How to get Arch Linux's GRUB bootloader to detect more distributions?

Tags: arch-linux, grub2

I have 14 distributions (including two different branches of Debian, stable and unstable) installed on my PC and only 10 of them (including Arch Linux) are detected by Arch Linux's GRUB bootloader. The ones not detected include:

- Fedora 27
- KDE Neon git unstable
- Linux Mint 18.3
- NixOS 17.09

while if it is at all relevant the following are detected:

- Arch Linux
- Debian 9 and unstable
- deepin 15.5
- Gentoo Linux
- Mageia 6
- openSUSE Tumbleweed (although its entry is unbootable as it says its kernel is not found, even though the exact kernel it is trying to boot does exist)
- PCLinuxOS
- Slackware 14.2
- Void

I should mention every one of them, except deepin, uses the Btrfs file system. deepin's installer wouldn't allow me to use Btrfs.

openSUSE Tumbleweed's GRUB bootloader is more comprehensive in the distros it detects.

Comment: Have you installed `os-prober` ?

Comment: Ya, 9 of the 10 distros (the 10th being Arch) that were detected wouldn't have been if os-prober wasn't installed. :)